# Is there a Redmine plugin for listing projects and their repositories?

Tags: repository, redmine, projects

Is there a `Redmine` plugin for listing projects and their repositories?

I have a lot of small projects not regularly used and it can be useful see which repositories they use without having to open the `Settings` page.